# Java program Class Menu

Tags: java

I have to use the function of this class in another class in `action_performed`. This code is giving me error.

```
public class Menu {

 public void Menu()
 {
     try {
         Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Image1.jpg"));\\to get image
         Image img1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Image2.jpg"));
         Image img2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Image3.png"));
         Image img3 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Image4.jpg"));
         Image img4= ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Image5.jpg"));
         Image img5= ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Image6.jpg"));
         JFrame f1=new JFrame("Menu");
         f1.setSize(400,200);
         f1.setVisible(true);
         JPanel P1=new JPanel();
         P1.setVisible(true);
         JButton b1=new JButton("Creamy Chocolate Cup");  
         b1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
         b1.add(P1);
         b1.setVisible(true);
         P1.add(f1);

     } catch (IOException ex) {


     }







}
}
```

Cant add more details and this is all I can  tell Just tell me how to solve this problem as quick as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line:

```
P1.add(f1);
```

This will give you a *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException* because you are trying to add a window to a container. It should work if you remove that line.

However, your code is totally incorrect. You are adding a JFrame to a JPanel and adding the JPanel to the JButton, it should be the opposite way around.

**For example, this will work for you:**

```
        public void Menu()
     {

             Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Image1.jpg"));

             JFrame f1=new JFrame("Menu");
             f1.setSize(400,200);

             JPanel P1=new JPanel();
             JButton b1=new JButton("Creamy Chocolate Cup");  
             b1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));

             P1.add(b1);
             f1.add(P1);
             f1.setVisible(true);
    }
```